# Error registering a module to create two field in the registration page

Tags: module, attributes, customer, custom

I tried to create a module to add two fields to the registration page, namely 'nickname' and 'recomendation' and it gives me an error.

**Vendor/Module/registration.php**

```
<?php

 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
 'Vendor_Module',
 __DIR__
);
```

**Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php**

```
<?php
  /**
   * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
   * See COPYING.txt for license details.
   */
  namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

  use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
  use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
  use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
  use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

  /**
   * Install data
   * @codeCoverageIgnore
   */
  class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
  {

      /**
       * CustomerSetupFactory
       * @var CustomerSetupFactory
       */
      protected $customerSetupFactory;

      /**
       * $attributeSetFactory
       * @var AttributeSetFactory
       */
      private $attributeSetFactory;

      /**
       * initiate object
       * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
       * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
       */
      public function __construct(
          CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
          AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
      )
      {
          $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
          $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
      }

      /**
       * install data method
       * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
       * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
       */
      public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
      {

          /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
          $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

          $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
          $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

          /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
          $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
          $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
          /**
           * customer registration form default field nickname
           */
          $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'nickname', [
              'type' => 'varchar',
              'label' => 'Alcunha',
              'input' => 'text',
              'required' => true,
              'visible' => true,
              'user_defined' => true,
              'sort_order' => 1000,
              'position' => 1000,
              'system' => 0,
          ]);
          //add attribute to attribute set
          $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'nickname')
              ->addData([
                  'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                  'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                  'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create'],
              ]);

          $attribute->save();
          /**
           * customer registration form default field recomendação
           */
          $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'recomendation', [
              'type' => 'varchar',
              'label' => 'Recomendação',
              'input' => 'text',
              'required' => true,
              'visible' => true,
              'user_defined' => true,
              'sort_order' => 1000,
              'position' => 1000,
              'system' => 0,
          ]);
          //add attribute to attribute set
          $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'recomendation')
              ->addData([
                  'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                  'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                  'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create'],
              ]);

          $attribute->save();

      }
  }
```

**Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <config  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
 <module name="Vendor_Module"  setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
    </sequence>
 </module>
```

After the setup:upgrade it gives no error but it tells me that there was nothing to import and my system went down saying that **There has been an error processing your request**

**var/report**

```
{"0":"Cannot read contents from file \"\/home\/criactiv\/public_html\/app\/design\/frontend\/TemplateMonster\/theme011\/etc\/module.xml\" Warning!file_get_contents(\/home\/criactiv\/public_html\/app\/design\/frontend\/TemplateMonster\/theme011\/etc\/module.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory","1":"#0 \/home\/criactiv\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Module\/ModuleList\/Loader.php(120): Magento\\Framework\\Filesystem\\Driver\\File->fileGetContents('\/home\/criactiv\/...')\n#1 \/home\/criactiv\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Module\/ModuleList\/Loader.php(81): Magento\\Framework\\Module\\ModuleList\\Loader->getModuleConfigs()\n#2 \/home\/criactiv\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Module\/ModuleList.php(72): Magento\\Framework\\Module\\ModuleList\\Loader->load()\n#3 \/home\/criactiv\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Module\/ModuleList.php(92): Magento\\Framework\\Module\\ModuleList->getAll()\n#4 \/home\/criactiv\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Module\/DbVersionInfo.php(138): Magento\\Framework\\Module\\ModuleList->getOne('Magento_Store')\n#5 \/home\/criactiv\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Module\/DbVersionInfo.php(54): Magento\\Framework\\Module\\DbVersionInfo->isModuleVersionEqual('Magento_Store', '2.1.0')\n#6 \/home\/criactiv\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Module\/DbVersionInfo.php(77): Magento\\Framework\\Module\\DbVersionInfo->isSchemaUpToDate('Magento_Store')\n#7 \/home\/criactiv\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Module\/Plugin\/DbStatusValidator.php(120): Magento\\Framework\\Module\\DbVersionInfo->getDbVersionErrors()\n#8 \/home\/criactiv\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Module\/Plugin\/DbStatusValidator.php(53): Magento\\Framework\\Module\\Plugin\\DbStatusValidator->getGroupedDbVersionErrors()\n#9 \/home\/criactiv\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\\Framework\\Module\\Plugin\\DbStatusValidator->beforeDispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#10 \/home\/criactiv\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/App\/FrontController\/BuiltinPlugin.php(69): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#11 \/home\/criactiv\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\App\\FrontController\\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#12 \/home\/criactiv\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#13 \/home\/criactiv\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#14 \/home\/criactiv\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(135): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#15 \/home\/criactiv\/public_html\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#16 \/home\/criactiv\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch()\n#17 \/home\/criactiv\/public_html\/index.php(39): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor))\n#18 {main}","url":"\/robots.txt","script_name":"\/index.php"}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your module.xml file.
I think you have  make some space in your xml file.
you have to define 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
at the top of the file.
Then it will work .

Comment: I have already encoding set, as seen above in the page listing. There's something else missing. I can't figure out what is.

Comment: you have to check your  module.xml file.
I believe , you have make some white space before declare encoding set.

Comment: I've checked that. I didn't left blank spaces neither after nor before the code. My main issue started with my fisrt attempt to register the module. Then I changed the code and now I'm able to deploy but the previous error from the fist attempt stills.  I think my server is down because of that. I wonder if there is some way to rollback the process and try again with my files configured.